# Do I need to use a factor for the ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test, shapiro-wilk-test

**The problem:**

A psychologist is interested in short-term working memory under (1) sleep deprivation, (2) a strong dose of caffeine, (3) following 8 hours sleep. They conduct a between subjects design. Each participant is given a list of 7 words to read, then asked to remember the words 30 seconds later.

The data set has three variables:

Participant: 1 to 90 (column name ‘PARTICIPANT’)

Group: 1 = sleep deprivation, 2 = strong dose of caffeine, 3 = 8 hours sleep (column name ‘GROUP’)

Score: 4 to 7 (column name ‘SCORE’)

Use R to analyse the data (anova_assessment). Write up the ANOVA and appropriate follow up tests.

**My question:**

How do I analyse the data in R? I have created a factor from the Groups, but am not sure if e.g. a VIF is possible? Was it correct to create a factor out of the 3 groups, then create a Shapiro Wilk Test. I decided to continue with a Wilcox test (please check if I have done it correctly with the factors) and then the Levene’s test. As I understand it I needed to do a Kruskal Wallis test instead of an ANOVA. Or should I have used the ezANOVA because of the factorial design (multiple independent?). What do I do now, if all of that was correct?

**What I have done:**

Regression:

`XGroup<-factor(anova_assessment$GROUP, c(1,2,3), labels=c('NO', 'CAFF','EIGHT'))`

`lm(formula = anova_assessment$SCORE ~ XGroup)`

Shapiro:

`byf.shapiro(anova_assessment$SCORE ~ XGroup)`

OR

```
no_sleep<-subset(anova_assessment, anova_assessment$GROUP==1)
caffeine<-subset(anova_assessment, anova_assessment$GROUP==2)
eight_hours<-subset(anova_assessment, anova_assessment$GROUP==3)

shapiro.test(caffeine$SCORE)

shapiro.test(no_sleep$SCORE)

shapiro.test(eight_hours$SCORE)
```

Wilcox:

```
NOSLEEP1<-factor(anova_assessment$GROUP, c(1,2,3), labels=c('NO','ELSE','ELSE'))
CAFFEINE1<-factor(anova_assessment$GROUP, c(1,2,3), labels=c('ELSE','NO','ELSE'))
EIGHT1<-factor(anova_assessment$GROUP, c(1,2,3), labels=c('ELSE','ELSE','NO'))

wilcox.test(anova_assessment$SCORE ~ NOSLEEP1)

wilcox.test(anova_assessment$SCORE ~ CAFFEINE1)

wilcox.test(anova_assessment$SCORE ~ EIGHT1)
```

Levene's Test:

`leveneTest(anova_assessment$SCORE, XGroup)`

Kruskal Test:

`kruskal.test(anova_assessment$SCORE ~ XGroup)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a HW assignment I will just give some hints. First, you only have one independent variable, so VIF is meaningless and you don't have a factorial design. Second, you can use `as.factor` within the `lm`. Third, I'm not sure why you are using Wilcox, maybe it's right, maybe not. Finally, rather than Shapiro, I would look at plots of the residuals. But, if you want to use Shapiro you can just do `shapiro.test(m1$residuals)`

Comment: The `as.factor` is new to me. Could you give me an example of how I could include it in the code?

We were told to use the Wilcox test instead of the t-test when the Shapiro Will test had a p-value below 0.05. 

Thank you very much about clarifying the independent variable. I was not sure whether the three groups each would be considered as individual independent variables or as one. 

Was my general use of the coding correct? Or do I have a significant fault in my understanding somewhere?

Comment: Something like m1 <- lm(y~as.factor(x)).   Using Wilcox when SW is significant is common, but I don't recoomend it (nor do a lot of others).  Tests of normality aren't very good. But, on an assignment, doing what the professor says is a good idea :-)